# XSL 1.0 Convert DateTime from GMT to Local Time

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working on creating an XSL stylesheet that processes an XML file and produces an HTML file. The challenge I am having is that the datetime value in the XML file looks like "2011-01-07T18:56:31Z".

From what I can figure out, the Z indicates that it is at GMT and I'd like to convert it to my local time but I'm not sure how to do that.

I can parse the datetime value and get the year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds but I need to convert it to my local time before I do that and I am unsure what, if any, functions exist in with XSL 1.0 that would allow me to do that.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`date:add()`](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/add/index.html) and [`date:difference`](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/index.html) EXSLT functions, for wich there are pure XSLT implementations written by Jenni Tennison.

Comment: Alejandro, thanks for the links, I'll definately look at adding those functions.

Comment: Oops, hit enter too soon. I do have a question though. In order to know how much I need to add to the GMT time, how do I calculate that value? In essence I need to look up the time zone of the locale and add that to the GMT but i don't know how to look up the time zone of the current locale.

Comment: @Kevin Moore: What's your new question? How to get the current dateTime, or how to extract time zone from a dateTime?

Comment: @Alejandro, my question would be how do I get the current time zone as the number of hours from GMT? I can then use that information and Jenni's date:add() function to determine what the local time is for my values.

Comment: @Kevin Moore: I'm talking about "current dateTime" and "time zone of given dateTime", and you are talking about "current time zone". I think you need to ask this as a separate question with input sample and desired output. Maybe it's already answered!